# RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit goes empty on leaving cell

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I am creating an xtragrid in a windows form with one of the columns having a cell type RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit . I select multiple items and when i key out of the cell, the cell goes blank.

Please point me in the right direction  and please explain what might be going on.

Comment: Think it may be something to do with hottracking

Comment: I have the same problem. Actually, you should see how your rows are validated. Do you use something like the `UpdateCurrentRow` method ? Provide us with some piece of code.

Comment: Actually I realised that I hadn't assigned any field of the underlying datasource to the new field. Once I created the appropriate underlying field and assigned it to the new column, the individual cell would retain its value and no longer go blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that I hadn't assigned any field of the underlying datasource to the new column. Once I created the appropriate underlying field and assigned it to the new column, the individual cell would retain its value and no longer go blank.